# i want to pass a select query in a stored procedure as an argumnet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made this procedure..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
            @pSelect nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @pSelect from tabel1
END
```

I want to pass a select query like from c# code to this stored procedure

```
MyProcedure("column1,column2");
```

How could I do this because stored procedure treat my parameter as a string and it behaves like

```
select N'column1,column2' from tabel1
```

pls help me

or provide a better option for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic sql inside the stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @pSelect nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'select ' + @pSelect + ' from tabel1';

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Here's a script to test the above stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE tabel1 (id int, data varchar(50))
INSERT INTO tabel1 VALUES(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc')

EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] 'id'
EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] 'data'
EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] 'id,data'
```

Comment: its giving me exception Invalid column name 'c'

Comment: Answer updated, you'll have to specify "nvarchar(max)" as the parameter, not just "nvarchar", since that will make it only use the first charafter of whatever you pass in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic SQL for the purpose, but it is not recommended. (More info here - [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html))

```
create procedure MyProcedure
@pSelect nvarchar
AS 
begin 
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
    set @sql='select ['+ @pSelect +'] from Table_1';
    exec sp_executesql @sql
end 
go

exec MyProcedure 'column1,column2'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `@pSelect` is having entire query then:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
            @pSelect nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    -- If you are@pSelect is having entire query
    exec (@pSelect)

    -- If you are passing only field list then following
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'select ' + @pSelect + ' from tabel1';
END
```